# Is there a way to increase the Item Limits for Boards in DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, backlog

We're using an inherited Scrum process in MS DevOps Service and recently created a new team that combines two old teams to provide a 'one-stop-shop' experience.  However, when we go to look at the Sprint Backlog or Taskboard, we don't see all the work items because we are over the 1000 item limit.

Is there a way for us or Microsoft to increase this limit?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I suspected from reading the online documentation.  I just wasn't sure if MSFT could increase our capacity but it doesn't sound like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each backlog can display up to 10,000 work items. If your backlog exceeds this limit, then you may want to consider adding a team and moving some of the work items to the other team's backlog.

For Taskboard , you can have up to 1,000 tasks on a task board. Like backlog, you can consider adding a team and moving some work items to the other team's task board.

Currently, the work item limits are as designed . I am afraid that these limits cannot be changed. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

For detailed limits ,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops#backlogs-boards-and-teams).

Comment: The link to UserVoice is not working

Comment: @bside As stated in the banner [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uservoice-pages-430e1a78-e016-472a-a10f-dc2a3df3450a?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) Microsoft has dropped UserVoice support; thus the link not working.